# Putting the values in pojo class list into hashmap

Tags: java, encapsulation, pojo

I have a pojo class in java. This is my pojo class

```
public class NetworkConfiguration {

    @SerializedName("GUID")
    @Expose
    private String gUID;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("Type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("WiFi")
    @Expose
    private WiFi wiFi;

    public NetworkConfiguration() {
    }
    public NetworkConfiguration(String gUID, String name, String type, WiFi wiFi) {
        super();
        this.gUID = gUID;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.wiFi = wiFi;
    }

    public String getGUID() {
        return gUID;
    }

    public void setGUID(String gUID) {
        this.gUID = gUID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public WiFi getWiFi() {
        return wiFi;
    }

    public void setWiFi(WiFi wiFi) {
        this.wiFi = wiFi;
    }

}
```

Now I am adding values in pojo class

```
 networkConfigurations.add(new NetworkConfiguration(items[i].getgUID(),
                           items[i].getName(), items[i].getType(), wiFi));
```

and then I am setting this list into hashmap

```
Map<String, Object> openNetworkConfigurationMap = new HashMap<>();

openNetworkConfigurationMap.put("NetworkConfigurations", networkConfigurations);
```

And i am setting this hashmap into a built in function but this is what happening

The values stored in my hashmap is

```
{NetworkConfigurations=[com.ariaware.enrolldevice.PolicyPojos.OpenNetworkConfiguration.NetworkConfiguration@3aa85c5, com.ariaware.enrolldevice.PolicyPojos.OpenNetworkConfiguration.NetworkConfiguration@fbb2b1a]}
```

As u know due to encapsulation my values cannot be read by the built in function so it gives me error

How can i store the values of list pojo class in hashmap

Comment: `NetworkConfiguration` needs a `toString()` maybe? That's why you're seeing that "weird" string instead of your fields.

Comment: let me try if i succeed. I will give u 5 dollars

Comment: @twanaeng you can specify model pojo instead of using object use this `Map<String, NetworkConfiguration>` to define your map

Comment: but my built in function only accepts Map<String,Object>